# How to stretch a mesh around multiple other meshes?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting

Hey all I am trying to model a squid and stretch a thin flap of skin between the tentacles near the base of the head and my problem is I don't know how to get a mesh to stretch between multiple tentacles like that.

I duped + combined them all into one mesh and tried a shrinkwrap with a plane and it just wasn't the effect I want or good and then in sculpt mode it was having issues as a plane is 2d and simple extruding it wasn't good since it was wrapped around other things.

Some other examples of what I'm trying to do to help visualize my problem. Canvas around tent poles, bat wings, or when sugar is being made around those sticks bakers use.

Just trying to stretch a mesh around some other meshes.

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please see a tutorial on armatures and weight painting.  Tutorials are certainly available on the site that has a name that rhymes with noonoob.  Perhaps there are tutorials here at BSE. Please show your work as multiple Blender Screen captures.  If you get lucky someone might create a new tutorial for you.  When someone appears new on this site it may help to show your work.  That is entirely your choice.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger "available on the site that has a name that rhymes with noonoob" is this a riddle or a site you are not allowed to tell? Or for insiders only?

Comment: @thissiteistoxic Canvas around tent poles can be done with cloth simulation. Bat wings are just faces between the bat's bones https://youtu.be/TIVn6wHqs-c

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger you don't understand my question. It has nothing to do with armatures and weight painting.


I'm trying to get a mesh stretched between another is the simplest way to describe it. Like how canvas would be stretched between tent poles or webbing between a frogs toes or something.